# Why position().top return wrong value in second table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables in first table its return position().top fine but when i click on second table then its return same value as in first table, how can i fixed it?

Why both table position().top return same?

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    offsetTop = $(this).position().top;
    console.log(offsetTop);
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv">
<h2>Table 1</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
   
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Click here this is first table, its return -1 in console</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <h2>Table 2</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Click here this is second table, its also return -1 in console why? how can i fix it? how can i get exactly position of this element?</td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `offset().top` ?

Comment: actually there is issue with offset() because i'm also using scrolling so there is offset() is not working properly thats why i 'm using position()

Comment: Ok so offset() is not working, thus you are using position(), which means you have tested this before using, right??

Comment: yes its tested...

Comment: Classic XY problem.  You tried offset(), didn't work, so you tried position(), also didn't work - so you asked why position() doesn't work instead of why offset() doesn't work or even *what you **actually** want*.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you trying to get the `top` relative to the `screen top`, and not relative to it's parent.

In this case you should use `offset()` and substruct the `window.scrollY`

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    offsetTop = $(this).offset().top - window.scrollY;
    console.log(offsetTop);
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
#d {
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d"></div>
<div class="myDiv">
<h2>Table 1</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
   
    <tbody>
      <tr id="2">
        <td>Click and see how its top changed with scroll</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <h2>Table 2</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>See how its top changed with scroll</td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I read that P.O. want it to be relative to screen top and no to document top. thats why he not use `offset()`. in the answer I show how to use `offset()` such it be relative to screen top

Answer (score 0):

You can get `table` `position` and sum with `tr` `position`, in fact, `position()` return element position depend on own parent position.

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    offsetTop = $(this).position().top;
    offsetTopParent = $(this).parents('table').position().top;
    
    //console.log(offsetTop); // return tr offset
    //console.log(offsetTopParent); // return table offset
    console.log(offsetTop + offsetTopParent);
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv">
  <h2>Table 1</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Click here this is first table, its return -1 in console</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h2>Table 2</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Click here this is second table, its also return -1 in console why? how can i fix it? how can i get exactly position of this element?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Click here this is second table, its also return -1 in console why? how can i fix it? how can i get exactly position of this element?</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m I add nothing! what do you talking about? which extra scroll!? | let OP decide which answer is right, not you. Refer first comment!

Comment: @freedomn-m It's OP code, not mine, OP wan to use scroll on `.myDiv`

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing that out.  I still think OP's is an XY problem, but you've provided a solution without using .offset() as requested in the comments.